# Proving a Two-Step recursive sequence is bounded (Olympiad problem)

Tags: sequences-and-series, contest-math, recurrence-relations

Could I have some hints on the following problem (British mathematical Olympiad Round 2, 2020 Q4)

*A sequence $b_1, b_2, b_3, . . .$ of nonzero real numbers has the property that
$$b_{n+2}=\frac{b_{n+1}^2-1}{b_n}$$
for all positive integers n.
Suppose that $b_1 = 1$ and $b_2 = k$ where $1 < k < 2$.*

*(i) Show that there is some constant $B$,
depending on $k$, such that $−B ≤ b_n ≤ B$ for all $n$.*

*(ii) Show that, for some $1 < k < 2$, there
is a value of n such that $b_n > 2020$.*

I don't really have much ideas for part (i). I tried analysing the sequence $b_{n+1} - b_n$ but I didn't get too far.

For part (ii) if we set $k=2$ each term of $b_n$ are consecutive integers so i think showing there exists some left limit ${k\nearrow 2}$ then it might prove the result.

Comment: don't you rather mean $b_{\color{red}2}=k$ ?

Comment: Sorry yes I'll fix it

Comment: @Arizus FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24b_%7Bn%2B2%7D%3D%5Cfrac%7Bb_%7Bn%2B1%7D%5E2-1%7D%7Bb_n%7D%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24b_2%3Dk%24&p=2), I found the closely related [How to show that $a_{n+2}=\frac{a_{n+1} ^2 -1}{a_n}$ is bounded?](/q/3912591) and [Equivalent Recurrence Relations](/q/3535955). There are also several AoPS threads, e.g., [BMO Round 2 2020 P4](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2040996p14437166), [Radius of convergence of a sequence](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2012993p14115940), ...

Comment: @Arizus (cont.) and [Bounding b_n depending on b_2](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2437270p20164868).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting together a few things from the various provided links, I think I can help without leaving out too many steps--other than some tedious algebraic manipulation.

---

Given the following recurrence:
$$b_{n+2} = \frac{b_{n+1}^2-1}{b_n} \tag1\label1$$
we wish to prove
$$
\begin{gather}
(\exists B(k))(\forall n |b_n| < B(k)) \tag{A}\label{A} \\[1ex]
1 < k < 2 \implies (\exists n)(b_n > 2002) \tag{B}\label{B}
\end{gather}
$$
First, we can rearrange the recurrence a bit to get
$$b_nb_{n+2}-b_{n+1}^2 = -1 \tag2\label\2$$
The LHS expression is equal to $-1$ for all $n$, so we can look at two consecutive iterations and set them equal:
$$
\begin{align}
&b_nb_{n+2} - b_{n+1}^2 = b_{n-1}b_{n+1} - b_n^2 \implies \\[1ex]
&b_n(b_{n+2} + b_n) = b_{n+1}(b_{n-1} + b_{n+1}) \implies \\[1.5ex]
&\frac{b_{n+2} + b_n}{b_{n+1}} = \frac{b_{n+1} + b_{n-1}}{b_{n}} = \frac{b_n + b_{n-2}}{b_{n-1}} = \cdots = \frac{b_1+b_3}{b_2} = \frac{1+k^2-1}{k}= k\tag3\label3
\end{align}
$$
That quotient is true for all $n$ as well, but it's still a recurrence, and we can rewrite it as:
$$b_{n+2} - kb_{n+1} + b_n = 0 \tag4\label4$$
Now this part I'm not clear on personally, but with recurrences, if you can write equations of this form for the recurrence, you can convert the equation to a characteristic polynomial by substituting $x^i$ for $b_{n+i}$. Here, that gives us
$$x^2 - kx + 1 = 0 \tag5\label5$$
The complex roots of this equation are $(r,s) = (\frac12 (k + z), \frac12(k-z))$, where $z$ is the complex square root $z = \sqrt{k^2-4}$. The really cool thing about these recurrences is that with the roots of the polynomial in hand, we can write an explicit expression for $b_n$:
$$b_n = cr^n + ds^n \implies b_n = c\left(\frac{k+z}{2}\right)^n + d\left(\frac{k-z}{2}\right)^n \tag6\label6$$
where $c$ and $d$ are constants based on the initial conditions. We know $b_1 = 1, b_2 = k$, so we can create a system of equations:
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
\frac12 c(k+z) + \frac12 d(k-z) &=2 \\[0.5ex]
\frac14 c(k+z)^2 + \frac14 d(k-z)^2 &=4k \\ 
\end{array} 
\right.
$$
The solution to the system is $c = \frac1z, d=-\frac1z$. So our final explicit equation is:
$$b_n = \frac1z \left(\left(\frac{k+z}{2}\right)^n - \left(\frac{k-z}{2}\right)^n \right) = \frac1z(r^n - s^n) \tag7\label7$$
Now, even though all of the solutions to this (for integer $n$) are real, we can take advantage of the complex nature of the two roots. First, note that $r$ and $s$ are complex conjugates. Adding them together gives $k$, and multiplying them gives $1$. Any time a polynomial has complex roots, they will come in conjugate pairs. We could write our roots a bit differently:

$$r,s = \frac k2 \pm i \sqrt{1-\frac{k^2}{4}} = p \pm iq$$

We often plot complex numbers as vectors on the complex plane, pointing away from the origin to the point $(p,q)$. Now this is cool: the distance formula works with complex numbers, giving the magnitude of the vector as $|p+iq| = \sqrt{p^2+q^2}$. But conveniently for our use, we have:

$$|r| = \sqrt{\left(\frac k2\right)^2 + 1-\frac{k^2}{4}} = \sqrt{\frac{k^2}{4} + 1-\frac{k^2}{4}} = 1$$

The same will be true for $s$, as complex conjugates have the same magnitude. This is a **unit vector**, so its end lies on the unit circle. And that's really convenient. When you multiply two complex numbers, you cause a rotation: you multiply the magnitudes, but add the angles (from the positive $x$ axis) of the two vectors. But if you multiply two unit vectors, with magnitude $1$, the product will still have magnitude $1$--it will merely have rotated partway around the unit circle.

And since exponentiation is just repeated multiplication, each higher power is just a further rotation around the circle. Complex conjugates have the same angle but reflected around the $x$ axis, so $r^n$ and $s^n$ will always remain complex conjugates.

OK, we're almost there. Remember we wrote $(r,s) = p \pm iq$ earlier. Since the complex vectors all lie on the unit circle, $|p| \le 1, |q| \le 1$. And indeed this will be true for all powers of $r$ and $s$. If we *subtract* complex conjugates, we get $p+iq - (p-iq) = p-p+iq+iq = 2qi$. Since $|q| \le 1$, $|2qi| \le 2i$.

We have to divide by $z$, which is conveniently imaginary and rids us of the $i$, giving:
$$b_n = \frac{2q}{\sqrt{4-k^2}} \implies \color{blue}{|b_n| < \frac{2}{\sqrt{4-k^2}} = B(k)}$$
Which is the request of (A). The request of (B) comes by setting $b_n=2002$:
$$2002 < \frac{2}{\sqrt{4-k^2}} \implies 2002^2 < \frac{4}{4-k^2} \implies 2002^2(4-k^2) < 4 \implies k^2 > \frac{4(2002^2-1)}{2002^2}$$

We can see that $k$ will be close to, but necessarily smaller than, $2$. QED.

Comment: Side note: the actual values of $b_n$ can be expressed as polynomials $P(k)$. Starting from $n=1$ they are $1,k,k^2-1,k^3-2k,k^4-3k+1,k^5-4k^3+3k \cdots$. If the value chosen for $k$ is the root of one of these polynomials, it's possible that you'll end up with a divide by zero error! For instance, $k \ne 1, \sqrt2, \phi, \sqrt3, \cdots$. Consider $\sqrt3$, for which the sequence is $(1,\sqrt3,2,\sqrt3,1,0,-1,\frac00)$. So $B(k)$ is not a continuous function.

Comment: Bonus side note: the polynomials can be generated as partial sums of:

$$b_n(k) =\sum_{j=1}^{\left\lfloor \large\frac{n+1}{2} \normalsize\right\rfloor} (-1)^{j+1} \binom{n-j}{j-1} k^{n+1-2j}$$

These are the $n$th iterations, which aren't the most important things to examine, but they *do* look cool when graphed with their bound:

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/5k7trehrwr